# ubuntu 22.04 not detecting hdmi port

Tags: 22.04, hdmi

First of all, I'm a total newbie to Linux and Ubuntu.
On a HP laptop, Intel I5 with integrated graphics, Windows 11.
I managed to make a partition & install Ubuntu 22.04.
But Ubuntu doesn't seem to find the hdmi port (which Windows does, so the problem is not with the port/cable/monitor).
Can anybody help ?